# Clustering of variable length trajectories in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I have a dataset that comprises several spatial path trajectories of variable lengths (i.e. a time series of X & Y coordinates). I am looking to group these based on the similarities of their shape (e.g. trajectories that are circular would be grouped together, trajectories that are a triangle would be grouped together), with a preference for using hierarchical agglomerative clustering. The data is currently in a single data frame with a grouping column (trajectoryName) and column for the timestamp and the X & Y coordinates.

What packages could I use to analyse these (essentially 3D) data? The R packages that I have found don't seem to be able to handle these groups of three dimensional data, and only offer solutions for either single observations or 2D datasets.